# PHP, SQL - getting fetch where table id = user id and count other table where row is = user id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Thanks for helping, first I will show code:

```
$dotaz = "Select * from customers JOIN contracts where customers.user_id ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' and contracts.customer_contract = ".$_SESSION['user_id']." order by COUNT(contracts.customer_contract) DESC limit $limit, $pocetZaznamu ";
```

I need to get the lists of users (customers table) ordered by count of `contracts(contracts table)`

I tried to solve this by searching over there, but I can't... if you help me please and explain how it works, thank you! :) `$pocetZanamu` is Number of records.

I need get users (name, surname etc...) from table customers, ordered by number of contracts in contracts table, where is contract_id, customer_contract (user id)..

Comment: Looks like you're missing a set of single quotes.

Comment: This solution show me just 1 users of 3 users, but not list, and yes a fetching this in while, but it's show me only 1 record

Answer (score 0):

This should do it where  is the column name you are counting.

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;
$dotaz = "Select COUNT(`customer_contract`) AS CNT, `customer_contract` FROM `contracts`   WHERE `user_id`=$id GROUP BY `customer_contract` ORDER BY `CNT` DESC";
```

Depending on what you are doing you may want to store the results in an array, then process each element in the array separately.

```
while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)){
  $contracts[$row[1]] = $row[0];
}

foreach ($contracts AS $customer_contract => $count){
  Process each user id code here
}
```

Not sure what you are counting.  The above counts the customer_contract for a table with multiple records containing the same value in the  customer_contract column.  
If you just want the total number of records with the same user_id then you'd use:

```
$dotaz = "Select 1 FROM `contracts`   WHERE `user_id`=$id";
$results = $mysqli->query($dotaz);
$count = mysql_num_rows($results);
```

Comment: It's showing  Unknown column 'contracts.customer_contract' in 'field list' i tried to get contracts.customer_contract to `` and I checked name of column and it's correctly

Comment: I assumed you stored the filed name in contracts.customer_contract as that is what you were using in your expression.  The syntax I would use is "COUNT(\`SQL_FieldName\`) AS CNT,\`SQL_FieldName\` FROM..."  where SQL_FieldName is the name of the field you are trying to count. The ",\`SQL_FieldName\`" will show both (and only both) the count and the value of the counted field.

Comment: Now I did it where you only query the contracts.

Comment: I believe the $_SESSION['user_id'] in the query string would have thrown an error.  That's why I added the $id=$_SESSION['user_id']

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to do.  If you need the customer name in place of user_id then you need to join the customer table. This should get you rows that look like "CNT|customer_contract|user_id"